# application independent soap message handler

Tags: java, web-services

I have a web services application in weblogic10.3. I used SOAP message handler for logging. But now I have to include my soap message handler code for logging in every package. Is there any way to create a jar for this and include it with whatever application we want. If yes please tell. Thanks..

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to include in every package? what advantage you will get it to log the same info from each package (if by package you mean different code layers at the service side)?

Comment: In every packages we have several web services for which i need to get logs. and in web services i used @SOAPMessageHandlers annotation in which i have given the name of java file as follows
          className="empdet.emplog"
I know it's deprecated but it was requirement. but now i have to add this java file(for logging) in every package. and it's not giving the same info.

Answer (score 2):

`@SOAPMessageHandlers` have been deprecated so better you should not use it.

I would recommend you to implement `SOAPHandler<MessageContext>` interface and override the methods `handleRequest()`
,`handleResponse()` and 'handleFault()`. The messageContext contains the details of incoming/outgoing SOAP message/fault.

The implementing class needs to be added as a `HandlerChain` in the SOAP contract. If all your service packages are in just one deployable war\ear, you don't need to create a separate Jar to contain this single `SOAPHandler` implemenation.

Please refer this link for more details.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv_rpc/handlers.html

For full sample example, below link would be helpful:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-soap-handler-example/

Comment: I already said that i have to use this deprecated annotation only according to our requirement and i already have a class which extended generic handler. I can not use HandlerChain annotation.